# What is the name of the idea that two expressions are equal if they share the same properties?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the name of the idea that if two expressions share the same properties, they are equal?
For example:

Let x = 1. x adopts all the properties of 1. x=1 because it has all the properties of one. This is more applicable if x=2-1 or something more complicated.

Comment: All that comes to my mind is substitution. If two expressions are equal, you may substitute one for the other at any given point if it suits your needs (e.g., adding zero to an equation to simplify factoring).

Answer (score 1):

Leibniz's law of identity would be a philosopher's answer. In some mathematical contexts, one property in common can establish equality. For example, in set theories with the axiom of extensionally, two sets are equal iff they have the same elements. Their other properties are then guaranteed to match.